# Python, como inverter uma lista encadeada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista-encadeada

Olá, preciso criar uma função que recebe uma lista não ordenada na estrutura de nós e ela deve inverter a ordem dos elementos dessa lista, eu tentei fazer um `L[::-1]` pra inverter a lista mas isso não funcionou, tentei bastante e não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Já tenho as classes implementadas, segue:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext


class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __str__(self):
        tmp = self.head
        lstr = ''
        while tmp != None:
            lstr += str(tmp.data) + ' '
            tmp = tmp.getNext()
        
        return lstr

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def add(self,item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.getNext()

        return count

    def search(self,item):
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.getNext()

        return found

    def remove(self,item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.getNext()

        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.getNext()
        else:
            previous.setNext(current.getNext())
```

a função pra inverter a lista se parece com isso:

```
def inverterLista(L : UnorderedList):
    # solução
    return L
```

Aqui alguns testes:

```
L = UnorderedList()
L.add(1)
L.add(2)
L.add(3)
L.add(4)
L.add(5)
print(f'Lista antes: {L}')
L = inverterLista(L)
print(f'Lista depois: {L}')
```

Peço a ajuda de vocês, sou iniciante no python e ainda não tinha visto nada parecido com isso, também não achei nada sobre como fazer isso em python, então, como eu poderia inverter essa lista encadeada?

Answer (score 0):

acrescentei na classe UnorderedList uma nova função chamada inverter(), ficando assim a nova classe:

```
class UnorderedList:

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.lstr=None


def __str__(self):
    tmp = self.head
    self.lstr = ''
    while tmp != None:
        self.lstr += str(tmp.data) + ' '
        tmp = tmp.getNext()

    return self.lstr

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.head == None

def add(self, item):
    temp = Node(item)
    temp.setNext(self.head)
    self.head = temp

def size(self):
    current = self.head
    count = 0
    while current != None:
        count = count + 1
        current = current.getNext()

    return count
def inverter(self):
    v = self.lstr
    tam = len(v)
    l_inv = ''

    while tam >= 0:
        l_inv += v[tam - 1]
        tam -= 1


    return l_inv


def search(self, item):
    current = self.head
    found = False
    while current != None and not found:
        if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            current = current.getNext()

    return found

def remove(self, item):
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    found = False
    while not found:
        if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()

    if previous == None:
        self.head = current.getNext()
    else:
        previous.setNext(current.getNext())
```

Após isso se testarmos dessa maneira abaixo dá certo:

```
L = UnorderedList()
L.add(1)
L.add(2)
L.add(3)
L.add(4)
L.add(5)


print(f'Lista antes: {L}')
print(f'Lista depois: {L.inverter()}')
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, mas o sort não funciona para esse problema vide que retornou o seguinte erro: AttributeError: 'UnorderedList' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: mofiquei a solução, veja se satisfaz o que você queria